# Debug/Run from Visual Studio 2017 very slow after one build

Tags: c, performance, visual-studio-2017, ide

I'm working with simple c/c++ console projects in Visual Studio 2017.

After a build, if I run/debug it from within the IDE (**Ctrl+F5** or **F5**), there's always a strange wait of tens of seconds before it actually runs (e.g. if I `printf` on the first line of my `main()`, it won't show until after the long "wait")

If there's no build after this first run, and I **Ctrl+F5** or **F5** again, it runs fast and normal. If then I change some source code and rebuild it, the strange wait appears again.

This slows down the dev iterations so much, and definitely feels wrong. Just wonder if any guru here can point me to a solution/workaround?

Thanks in advance！

Comment: While I feel with you, I do somehow miss the question for which you hope to get an answer.

Comment: That is a description, quite a similar one. Would you like to ask a question? I think of something which ends in a "?" and can be answered. Alternatively you could describe how an answer should look like. For example, would "Yes, I confirm your observations." be a satisfactory answer?

Comment: Aha, reasonable, let me change the original text

Comment: Also, if you can improve your question, please do so by [edit]ing it, not by adding a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, mystery resolved -- it's my Avira antivirus. Somehow after installing VS2017, it starts to scan each new exe I generated. After setting my dev folders as exceptions, things are a lot quicker. Finally.

Comment: I disabled the Windows Defender and now it runs fast as it supposed to be. I am on a corporate network and we also use another antivirus solution. It may be a conflict or a combination of those two apps running simultaneously. Before fiddling with VS settings or apply tweaks I would give disabling the AV a try.